# Filepath to Chosen for "Home Page" option - Which function?

Tags: functions, homepage, directory

Someone using my plugin/theme surprised me by making their site address different than their install address with the *"Enter the address here if you want your site homepage to be different from the directory you installed WordPress."* option.

Example:

They've installed at:

**www . thesite . com / blog /**

And their actual wordpress site shows up at

**www . thesite . com**

Which function properly delivers the *filepath* (not URL) leading to **www . thesite . com** ? I have a unique case where this is needed.

Considering random cases, it would have to work if a user chooses **www . thesite . com / random / location /**

---

**CLARIFICATION:**

If the site as a whole was installed at **www . thesite . com / blog** virtually every URL and *file*path is relative to that location. BUT if they modify their settings so that the blog is shown at a different spot OTHER than the install director ( such as **www . thesite .com** OR **www . thesite . com / somerandom / chosen / url** ) what I need is the FILE PATH to that location.

REASON: I have a network of sites running, and the plugin installs certain network oriented files at their "home" location.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading up on the site_url() function.
Take a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url
and specifically, read the difference between:

site_url() & home_url()

Then you could look at parse_url() or ABSPATH as suggested before by @NickJAB

Comment: I'm probably not explaining things properly. I'll update the question for clarity

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you are looking for the absolute path to Wordpress. ABSPATH is a constant defined in the wp-config.php file that you may be able to use for this purpose. You can see it by:

```
<?php echo ABSPATH; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think they actually moved their main wordpress `index.php` and `.htaccess` files from `www.thesite.com/blog` to `www.thesite.com` root.

And changing is been made to `index.php`

Edit on `index.php` file:

Before:

`require('./wp-blog-header.php');`

After:

`require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');`